# Different types of hyperlinks in Word document

Tags: openxml, wordprocessingml

I'm writing a small app the takes a path as input and then fetches every docx file in that path, replacing every hyperlink with a keyword.

The strange thing is that I found two sorts of hyperlinks, the first one is from WordprocessingDocument ExternalRelationships and the other one is from finding every xml-node matching `<w:insrText/>` starting with HYPERLINK.

Are there any more ways a hyperlink can be used in a docx file or even better is there a better way through the ooxml-api finding every hyperlink in the document?

Answer (score 0):

Those two are it and yes there are two different ways of storing the same thing in Word.